# To store value in array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below code I am getting the value of a dynamic checkbox. I want to store the values in an array. For instance, `arr[0]` should hold `empid`, `empname`, `empno` .. `a[n]`.

`arr[0]` should hold `empid`, `empname`, `empno`
.......`arr[n]` should hold `empid`, `empname`, `empno`

```
var selectedIds = [];
function CheckRow(EmpID, EmpName, EmpNo) { 
    $(":checked").each(function () {

        selectedIds.push("EmpID=" + EmpID);
        selectedIds.push("EmpName=" + EmpName);
        selectedIds.push("EmpNo=" + EmpNo);

        // selectedIds.push($(this).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: not clear what is required..

Comment: @vinayakj i want to hold empid,empname ,empno to arr[0] ..arr[n]upto no of checked values..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to store objects in your array. Just like this:

```
var selectedIds = [];
function check_row(empId, empName, empNo) { 
    $(":checked").each(function () {
        selectedIds.push({
             empId : empId,
             empName : empName,
             empNo : empNo
        });
    });
}
```

But I still don't understad why you need it.

Answer (score 0):

To include each group of values in a separate element in the array, group them together in an object:

```
var selectedIds = [];
function CheckRow(EmpID, EmpName, EmpNo) { 
    $(":checked").each(function (){
        selectedIds.push({empid:EmpID, empname:EmpName, empno:EmpNo});
    });
}
```

You can then recover values, e.g.

```
selectedIds[0].empname;
```